# Boot order won't change

Tags: 11.10, grub2, boot-order

Well, I've tried almost everything to set my boot order to what I need it to be. But it just won't.

- I changed `/etc/default/grub` and updated grub,
- I used the *startupmanager*
- I even gave *grub-customizer* a try

Each time it says everything's fine but when I restart my secondary OS is shown at first, while it should not be there

I'm using  *Ubuntu 11.10 64bits + Jolicloud 1.2*.  How do I change the boot order?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized -- OP answered this question with: "Couldn't hold anymore, so I installed my systems on the inverse order by making the last one installed my primary OS ~ Now it's working fine."

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the order in the boot menu is determined by the leading numbers for each sub-file in grub.d...Like 10_linux adds to the menu before 40_custom.  So if you want to move an OS up you add it to the menu with a 07_reallycustom entry

Answer (score 0):

You must make some changes manually to your grub system.  You will find all the necessary here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602 . As explain there make sure you make some back-ups of your files.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't hold anymore, so I installed my systems on the inverse order by making the last one installed my primary OS ~ Now it's working fine.

Thanks for your time.